# Are subkeys full-fledged keys in gnupg?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, gnupg

I understand the key management and security benefits of using subkeys. However, I'm not sure whether subkeys are partial keys with limitations or full-fledged keys (just as the master key). Both the master key and the subkey look like a pair of numbers to me so that I'm wondering whether the word *sub* really comes from their usage but not their capability.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, they're fully fledged keys.](https://wiki.debian.org/Subkeys)

The difference is that you have a master key, which you probably don't want to revoke or let expire often, and subkeys, which you actually use for crypto.

The subkey can be revoked, expire etc, but it's also proof that you're the owner of the master key. In essence, people trust *you* (i.e. you master key), but you just use the subkey. So, when the life time of one of the subkeys ends, you just use a new one – and don't have to rebuild your web of trust.

Comment: Thank you for a confirmative answer. I understand the subkey usage scenario, but the gnupg implementation makes me feel like subkeys are second-class citizens there: `--list-keys` doesn't print their IDs, they have their special names such as `sub` and `ssb` which really mean `pub` and `sec`, and users can only add/delete subkeys from their master key, etc. Why doesn't gnupg simply list them as normal keys and let users decide the relationship among keys? In that way users may have sub-sub-keys as well and that's quite some flexibility.

Comment: Experience shows that users don't even understand the current gpg relationship model. Making it even more complicated won't help.

Comment: @Josef By putting all keys at the same level things are **simplified** rather than complicated. The stories I hear from people are that they often got confused by the different key names at first use. You will frequently see people ask in forum: What are `sub` and `ssb` keys? Instead, if you tell them they have a bunch of keys and show them some basic usage scenarios, they are likely to understand better. After all, most people simply expect a key pair at their very beginning, which means 2 instead of 4 keys. In contrast, if they know how to use subkeys, subsubkeys are almost the same.

Comment: @Cyker putting all keys on the same level breaks the web of trust. How do you expect me to change my keys if I lose my smartcard with the keys on it? Ask all 100+ people who signed my key to just sign this new key again, without any proof that it's really me?

Comment: @Josef Putting them at the same level in the sense that all keys are equally represented on the keyring. The difference in their usage should be defined by users themselves. Subkeys only give you 2 layers of management. But a general DAG can give you many layers. This is both flexible (user-defined) and clear (explicit topology of key relationship).

Comment: @cyker but that's exactly what Josef meant: You *don't* need to know the ID of the subkey. You *trust* the master key. The reason you've got subkeys is that they're worth "less" than your master key and can be replaced. If you start signing subkeys with subkeys, you assign as much importance to the signing subkey as to the master. And that makes the system intransparent.

Comment: @MarcusMüller By forming a multi-layer DAG, you reduce the chance of using the master key because you can use a subkey to sign subsubkeys. The less frequently you use the master key, the more secure it's likely to be. I'm not saying other people should trust any of your subkeys. They only trust your master key. But they are able to validate your subsubkeys using knowledge of your master key because there is a path from your master key. Subkeys don't have the same importance as the master, but that's defined by their relationship, not by their capabilities.

Comment: @Cyker this discussion here is moot, a) because that's not how it is done, so arguing it'd be better is kind of in vain, b) because this is not the GnuPG mailing list, c) your assumption "the less often you use the master key, the more secure" breaks down, because by signing a key with a subkey, you make a subkey a master key, in effect, and d) you're right, the subkeys have the same capabilities, but not the same relations as the master key. The difference is that you do not use sub keys to express that other keys are yours. Really.

Comment: @MarcusMüller c) is not true. Signing a subkey doesn't make it a master key, as hiring an engineer doesn't make a manager the CEO (usually the image of a company). But if a manager hires you, then you are part of the company, even if you are not hired by the CEO him/herself.

Comment: @cyker really, you're trying to define sub-subkeys as something useful, and all world agrees on not having sub-subkeys in PGP because it breaks the clear "if it's used to sign my own keys, it's a master key" mechanism. So, yeah, if you define your world to disagree with me, than you'll be in disagreement with me. I really don't see how an additional layer of keys that might get away increases security. However, I still think this discussion is in vain, so I think you won't be upset if I just end it here, if that's OK with you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not upset but I think the length discussion has probably outgrown this site's comment policy so I agree to stop here. I think in the end on some day you will suddenly understand what I mean here. Finally, the goal is not to disagree with anybody but to explore better ways of doing things than what they are right now.